# Flink Kafka connector support for KIP-392

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Does Flink Kafka connector support consuming from closest replica KIP-392?

We would like to avoid cross AZ data transfer and I couldn't find any option in KafkaSouce class that supports this feature.

Comment: Flink is built over plain Kafka Consumer classes, so should work to just set `client.rack` as a generic consumer property (`builder.setProperty`). What issues are you running into?

Comment: There is a similar question around KIP-708 Rack Awareness; I've asked in that ticket (since Flink doesn't support it at the moment) if the same applies for KIP-392. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-29398